# Regex to extract content from each line of a log file output from '_m' to the end of the line

Tags: regex, logfiles

Format of log line:

```
Xxx x xx:xx:xx xmmxxx XXXXXX: XXXXXXX:XXX: xxx_Mxxx_Xxxxxx_mxxxxxmmxx [XXX xxxx.
```

I want to extract from `'_m'` to the end of the line, removing the `'_'` before the `'m'`.

New to regex...

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, cant understand. Please explain clearly.... thanks

Comment: That would be pretty simple if you can guarantee there could be no "_m" in the data before that "_m". Can you?

Comment: There are multiple 'm' but no '_m'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your tool/language support look-behind, this works: match the first `_m` till `EOL`. also ignore the leading `_`

```
(?<=_)m.*
```

test with grep:

```
kent$  echo "Xxx x xx:xx:xx xmmxxx XXXXXX: XXXXXXX:XXX: xxx_Mxxx_Xxxxxx_mxxxxxmmxx [XXX xxxx."|grep -Po '(?<=_)m.*' 
mxxxxxmmxx [XXX xxxx.
```

Answer (score 1):

With `sed`:

```
sed -n 's/^.*_\(m.*$\)/\1/p' file
```

Answer (score 0):

It is quite easy:

This example is written in C# however the regex is quite general and will probably work anywhere:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"_(m.*)");  // If you look for _M the regex should be @"_(M.*)"

Match match = regex.Match(logLine);
if (match.Success)
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
```

Hope this will help you on your quest.